# Django chaining multiple queries together to return latest

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 3 separate models. I would like to be able to do a query on all tables and return the object with the latest date. What would be the best approach for this? I currently have them returned in a chain. All of the models contain an auto_now_add DateTimeField. Is it possible to filter the latest created object based on the chained queryset?

```
article_list = Article.objects.all()
issue_list = Issue.objects.all()
annual_list = Annual.objects.all()

result_list = list(chain(article_list, issue_list, annual_list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want only 1 object you can use max() with key

```
max(result_list, key=lambda x: x.date) #or whatever the name of the field is (should be same on all models)
```

on the same fashion if you want the whole list sorted by the date field you can use sorted() and give the above key